# PHP: MySQL query returning array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm wondering how I would issue a query from a PDO and have an array returned? Right now, I have

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}", $user, $pass);
```

Using a foreach loop, like so

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Locations ORDER BY City";
foreach($DBH->query($query)as $row) {
    echo $row['City'];      
}
```

I can get all the cities printed. However, I would like to store all the cities into an array. I tried to do it like this

```
$array = $DBH->query($query);
```

but that didn't work at all. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Locations ORDER BY City";

foreach($DBH->query($query) as $row) {
    $array[] = $row['City'];      
}
```

Comment: Not really possible, you have to iterate through results somehow.  If you don't like looking at it in your code, encapsulate it as a function.  But I don't see the point.

Answer (score 3):

You're using PDO, so you should be using [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://us.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

```
$stmt = $DBH->query($query);
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Done - And you're not using any loops.

Comment: wouldn't just plain `fetchAll()` return a nested array instead of one array with all `city` values?

Comment: Though I would prefer a loopless version like this, it simply doesn't work for me. When I tried echoing out the array with a foreach loop like below, I was able to get each city. With this, I don't even get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try:

```
$array = array();

foreach($DBH->query($query) as $row){
    array_push($array, $row['City']);     
}

print_r($array);
```